# How to solve video memory issue in laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, graphics-card, gaming

Whenever I try to access any game , I get the message "**can't find enough video memory**". Is there a way to resolve this issue?

I tried to access GTA vc but it also said that it can't find enough video memory. Wolfienstein 3D also said "**no video memory detected**". Even default MS Windows games, like Purble Palace said "**graphics acceleration is either not supported by your graphics card driver or it is disabled**".

My laptop is Asus x200 ma. It has a 2GB RAM (checked), and a standard VGA graphics card (checked).

My laptop is in warranty but I don't want to send it because the service center says that the warranty is of its hardware not its software.  They will take 800 INRs to install Windows 8.1 and they will install the drivers also.

My laptop has an HDMI port. I may not have installed the drivers but I am not sure, so I don't want to do anything to my laptop, yet. I may not have installed VGA drivers correctly.  I'm not sure how to check these things.

I'm hoping the problem is something I can fix without having to send it for service and have everything wiped.

Comment: Guys please help me. And please dont tell to buy or purchase another laptop.

Comment: Sorry to say, that machine was never made to play games on, it's for doing email & web surfing. 2GB RAM & an old Intel HD graphics chip is just not built for gaming. Try getting latest drivers from [Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx?lang=eng) (use the automated system on the left) & see if that might improve things a bit.

Comment: That means i can't play even low end games on my netbook?

Comment: You might get some low end stuff running with up to date drivers, but I'm not sure about something like GTA. I've never had a machine with onboard graphics myself, so I can only speak from anecdotal experience.

Comment: Ok, if i will give it to the service centre, then can i play that games?

Comment: It won't magically speed up what is essentially a machine made for web surfing, no. Did you try the new driver?

Comment: Nope because the drivers that were given to me with the package was of windows 8 64bit but i have windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: 'given to me' by whom? when?

Comment: The matter is that i had ordered it from an online shopping site. It was for the first time so we were not knowing about it anything. The delivery boy gave a CD which contains probably the drivers for windows 8 because on the cd it was written its only for win8 64 bit.

Comment: Then try the drivers from Intel.

Comment: I have tried many times but all the drivers after installation say only one thing "your computer does not fulfil the minimum requirements required by the driver".